# Как использовать список, который находится в родительском классе, в дочернем классе, который находится в другом файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

У меня есть родительский класс, который находится файле **test2.py**

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4]]

class main:
     l1 = []

     def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b

     def solve(self):
         main.l1.append(self.a+3)


     def printtt(self):
         import test3
         p = test3.Segm(self.a, self.b)
         p.printt()


for i in l:
    w = main(i[0], i[1])
    w.solve()
w.printtt()
```

А также дочерний файл в файле **test3.py**

```
class Segm():
     def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b

     def printt(self):
         import test2
         o = test2.main(self.a, self.b)
         print(o.l1)
```

Мне нужно использовать список (находящийся в родительском классе в другом файле) в дочернем, все работает, но оно выводит то что мне нужно 2 раза, возможно кто знает как сделать так чтобы список выводился только 1 раз?

Вывод

[4, 6]

[4, 6]

Comment: Почините табуляции. Тот код, который должен выполняться только при непосредственном запуске файла, но не при импорте, поместите в блок `if __file__ == "__main__": ...`

Comment: У меня в PyCharm один раз вывод, а в IDLE - два раза.

Comment: @Сергей Как-то странно я тоже у работаю в PyCharm, но у меня выводится 2 раза

Comment: странно. Но неважно, совет дан же выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать,
но предложу попробовать следующее:

**main.py**

```
from test3 import Segm                                     # +++


my_list = [
    [1, 2], 
    [3, 4]
]

class Main:
    l1 = []

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def solve(self):
        self.l1.append(self.a + 3)

    def printtt(self):
#         import test3
        segm = Segm(self)                                  # +++ (self)
        segm.printt()

for i in my_list:
    main = Main(i[0], i[1])
    main.solve()
    
main.printtt()
```

**test3.py**

```
class Segm():
     def __init__(self, parent):                # +++ parent
         self.parent = parent

     def printt(self):
         print(self.parent.l1)                  # +++ self.parent
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, вы все правильно поняли. А еще у меня  вопрос, можно будет как-то в файле teste3.py использовать self.a и self.b? Например вывести print(self.parent.l1, self.a)

Comment: @st040506 да, можно это будет `self.parent.a` и `self.parent.b` в модуле `test3.py`. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: И еще такой вопрос self.parent  это как замена self.a  и self.b? Зачем мы используем в файле main.py super().__init__(), я знаю, что super() применяют в дочерних классах, но такого применения я еще не видела. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить почему?

Comment: @st040506 sorry, если у вас есть другие проблема - задайте новый вопрос.